# kinect's rgb camera with camera_calibration

Tags: calibration, kinect, camera-calibration, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

The calibration tutorial applied to the kinect rgb camera searches for a service that isn't published by the openni driver. This results in

`rosrun camera_calibration cameracalibrator.py --size 8x5 --square 0.02994444 image:=/camera/rgb/image_color camera:=/camera`

`Waiting for service /camera/set_camera_info ...`

`Service not found`

Hasn't anybody used the camera_calibration package to obtain the intrinsic parameters of the kinect camera? I'd need them for the handeye calibration.

cheers

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9550/kinect%27s-rgb-camera-with-camera_calibration/) by [polmonso](https://answers.ros.org/users/344/polmonso/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2011-03-23

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The intrinsic calibration for the Kinect is already available in the Openni driver. [This answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/299/getting-the-calibration-parameters-of-the-kinect) describes where to find it.

You'll want to use the 'camera/rgb/camera_info' topic, which gives a [sensor_msgs/CameraInfo](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/CameraInfo.html) message.

---

Originally posted by [rreid](https://answers.ros.org/users/323/rreid/) with karma: 124 on 2011-03-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Use:
rosrun camera_calibration cameracalibrator.py --size 8x5 --square 0.02994444 image:=/camera/rgb/image_color camera_info:=/camera
("camera_info:=" instead of "camera:/")

---

Originally posted by [David Fischinger](https://answers.ros.org/users/489/david-fischinger/) with karma: 11 on 2011-10-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1